# How to get rid of voice bar over keyboard in Android 6?

Tags: keyboard, 6.0-marshmallow, google-voice-actions

I want to remove the horizontal bar with the microphone button (voice input) showing over Android 6 keyboard (marked with the red border).

[image]

I know which settings are supposed to control this behaviour and I'm able to accomplish the task in Android 5. Yet in Android 6 this seems not working as expected anymore.

Here is my Language settings (including Voice typing):

[image]

And here is my Ok Google settings:

[image]

Most interesting part is that while the Voice typing option is off, its summary does actually read "automatic" (which is suspicious and illogical). Yet in Android 5 it works the same way, and the voice input bar is not showing over keyboard.

One more thing to note is that in Android 6, with the given settings, the voice input does not function - that is pressing the microphone button has no effect at all. Yet the horizontal bar wastes valuable space.

I've sent a feedback to Google - no responce. I've tried to send a message to a couple of public Google's emails (including published in Google Play as contacts!) and got responces from robots that those are no-reply emails. So there is no support from Google. I hope the community can help to solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

<sup>PS. Should we have `Voice typing` tag (which I'm unable to add)? `google-voice-actions` is most close from existing tags, but still not completely correct.</sup>

Comment: I think you forgot to check on **Settings - Language & input - Google Keyboard - Preferences - Voice input key**?

Comment: As for the tag: I think the [voice-recognition](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/voice-recognition/info) tag might be what you were looking for (the opposite of "text-to-speech").

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't have such an option there. There are only 3: Auto-capitalization, Double-space period, and Sound on keypress.

Comment: Seems like the only solution is to install a 3-rd party keyboard - they are numerous, provide much more options than Google, and work without its issues.